# How to Play Music in Cycle with Omxplayer?

Tags: music

I would like to setup a song backward in a corridor by `omxplayer` but I cannot find any parameter for it [here](http://elinux.org/Omxplayer)

```
omxplayer music.mp3
```

---

How can you play the same music song in cycle?

Comment: Do you mean to repeat the song? For this there seeems to be the `--loop` option...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In @andrew.46's comment

```
omxplayer --loop song.mp4
```